# Loop Data By Columns

Tags: excel, vba

Loop Data By Columns

I have been using the following code to populate sequential textboxes in a UserForm where the each array is compiled of columns. In the following the sequence of cell values would be:-

```
For Draw 1 TxtBox1 = B5, TxtBox2 = C5, TxtBox3 = D5, TxtBox4 = E5, TxtBox5 = B6, TxtBox6 = C6 etc Through to Cell E8
For Draw 2 TxtBox1 = Y5, TxtBox2 = Z5, TxtBox3 = AA5, TxtBox4 = AB5, TxtBox5 = Y6, TxtBox6 = Z6 etc

Option Explicit

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lngCtrlLoop As Long
Dim lngRowLoop As Long
Dim tbCounter As Long
Dim vCols As Variant
Dim vCol As Variant
Dim DrawToColsDict As Object
Private Sub userForm_Initialize()
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
End Sub
Private Sub cmdCallResult_Click()
    Set DrawToColsDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
        With DrawToColsDict
            .Add "Draw 1", Array("B", "C", "D", "E")
            .Add "Draw 2", Array("Y", "Z", "AA", "AB")
        End With
        With Me
                vCols = DrawToColsDict(.cboDrawNumber.Value)
            tbCounter = 1
                For lngRowLoop = 5 To 14
                    For Each vCol In vCols
                        .Controls("txtBox" & tbCounter).Text = ws.Cells(lngRowLoop, vCol).Text
                    tbCounter = tbCounter + 1
                    Next
                Next
        End With
End Sub
```

I am looking for code where the informaton is held in columns so all the TextBoxes per "Draw" (Combox Value) will be populated from a single Column
For Draw 1 TxtBox1 = B5, TxtBox2 = B6, TxtBox3 = B7 TxtBox4 = B8 TxtBox5 = B9 etc
For Draw 2 TxtBox1 = C5, TxtBox2 = C6, TxtBox3 = C7 etc

A similar solution would be most appreciated

NOTE: I have tried to format the sample code in this enquiry using the "Code" option however, this would not format all the code.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Why don't you just edit the code?

Comment: Your question has been answered by @CDP1802 , not by me. Post your questions regarding their answer beneath that answer. I merely wondered why you don't edit your own code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdCallResult_Click()

    Dim DrawToColsDict As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Dim vCol As Variant, tbCounter As Long

    Set DrawToColsDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With DrawToColsDict
        .Add "Draw 1", "B"
        .Add "Draw 2", "C"
    End With
    
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    With Me
        vCol = DrawToColsDict(.cboDrawNumber.Value)
        For tbCounter = 1 To 16
            .Controls("txtBox" & tbCounter).Text = ws.Cells(tbCounter + 4, vCol).Text
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution. I am a novice at VBA but do try to understand the syntax of the code and try to work out what is happening. In your solution I can see the relevance of most of the code but would appreciate verification of a couple of entries. What is the relevance of the tbCounter 1 To 16 unless it is an example range of textboxes. Next, I am really confused by (tbCounter + 4, vCol). Please can you explain. Many thanks – 
Denny57

Comment: @denny Do you have16 text boxes ? `TxtBox1 = B5` so row 5 is 1 + 4, `TxtBox2 = B6` so row 6 is 2 + 4

Comment: Thank You  . I  have run test code using a copy of "live" data  and after examining various  results I have managed to work out what range information need to be applied,  Thanks again for your help